# How to get all index name in postgresql using java

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to get all the index that has been created for a table using java.I know that to get primary key constraints name we can use

```
DatabaseMetaData meta=conn.getMetaData();
            rs = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tablename);
            while(rs.next()){
                constraintName = rs.getString(6);
            }
```

But is there anyway to get all the index name that is being created for table.

Comment: `DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name I got it.